# How to compare the extension of a file with different extensions in java

Tags: java

i want to compare the retrieved file extension with different valid extionsions according to my requirement in java  like,

```
 CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(reader), ';', '\'', 1);
    try{
        while ((lNextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            for(int i = 0;i < lNextLine.length; i++){
                String lFilename = lNextLine[0];
                String[] lext = lFilename.split("\\.");
                if(lext[1].equals("jpeg")||lext[1].equals("wmv")||lext[1].equals("doc")....){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: Your sample code assumes that `lFilename` contains only a single ".". It would be safer to use `lext[lext.length - 1]` instead of `lext[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all the extensions you want to check against in a `static HashSet` and then use `contains(...)` which is a **O(1)** operation.

```
static Set<String> supportedExtensions=new HashSet<String>();

    static
    {
      //populate supportedExtensions
    }

    while ((lNextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
    {
      for(int i = 0;i < lNextLine.length; i++)
      {
        String lFilename = lNextLine[0];
        String[] lext = lFilename.split("\\.");
        return supportedExtensions.contains(lext[lext.length - 1]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Pangea one more thing, how can i read a csv file from the second line of the file.

Comment: @rajasti277 You skip the first line. i.e. read it and ignore it. i guess you want it to skip the 1st line because it is a header right